# Difference between concat and ES6 spread operator for array manipulation in setState (React Hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm encountering this weird error that I still can't understand what's exactly is happening.

I'm updating a state array and want to parse new objects to that array with keeping the old ones.

The known method for me with ES6 was to use the **spread** operator as:

```
const [stories, setStories] = useState([]);
```

...

```
setStories(stories => [...stories, newStories]);
```

where **newStories** is also an array of objects.

But here I get the following output:

[console.log(stories)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcfU6.png)

while when I do the same with **concat** as:

```
setStories(stories => stories.concat(newStories));
```

It returns as expected:

[console.log(stories)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaQSm.png)

So far, I thought that these 2 methods would perform the same.

Also I found this article and that confirms my knowledge too, and contradicts with the above output that I'm getting.[See: **Best solution: Spread operator … & a wrapper**](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-add-to-an-array-in-react-state-3d08ddb2e1dc)

Comment: Well since `newStories` is also an array, you'll need to use `[...stories, ...newStories]`. If it was only a single story, you'd do `[...stories, newStory]` (or `stories.concat([newStory])` - notice the array literal)

Comment: Your usage is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take for instance this code from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
let parts = ['shoulders', 'knees'];
let lyrics = ['head', ...parts, 'and', 'toes'];
//  ["head", "shoulders", "knees", "and", "toes"]
```

As you can see by spreading the `parts` array into the `lyrics` array it pulls the data from the array. If you were to instead write:

```
let parts = ['shoulders', 'knees'];
let lyrics = ['head', parts, 'and', 'toes'];
//  ["head", ["shoulders", "knees"], "and", "toes"]
```

You would get the array instead.

If you take an array

```
[{name: 'story1'}, {name: 'story2'}]
```

and place it in your other array, you get:

```
setStories((stories) => [...stories, newStories]);
[[{name: 'story1'}, {name: 'story2'}]]
```

if you do it again, you get:

```
setStories((stories) => [...stories, newStories]);
[[{name: 'story1'}, {name: 'story2'}],[{name: 'story1'}, {name: 'story2'}]]
```

Because you are just placing the array into your other array.

If you want to remove the objects from your array, you must `spread` the object into your state.

```
setStories((prevstate) => [...prevstate, ...newStories]);
```

then you get:

```
[{},{},{},{}]
```

because by spreading you are taking the objects out of the array they are currently in.

As a side note I wouldn't recommend naming the parameter of your callback function the same name as your state, it becomes confusing as to what you are actually referencing. I've seen `prevstate` or in your case some would write `prevStories` etc. Just a recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to spread both the arrays to make a new array

```js
const story1 = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}]
const story2 = [{c: 3}, {d: 4}]

const newStories = [...story1, ...story2];
console.log(newStories);
```

Instead if you use it only for one array, it would create a sub array inside the `newArray`

```js
const story1 = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}]
const story2 = [{c: 3}, {d: 4}]

const newStories = [story1, ...story2];
console.log(newStories);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. The `...` spread operator spreads an array into a new array. However, your usage is incorrect:

```js
setStories(stories => [...stories, newStories]); // ❌
setStories(stories => [...stories, ...newStories]); // ✅
```

The reason why the first line doesn't work is if `newStories` is an array (which it likely is by the name), the `...` is necessary to destructure and inject all the array's items individually into the new array.

This illustrates the bug a bit clearer:

```
const a = [1,2]
const b = [3,4]
const c = [...a, b] // [1,2,[3,4]] ❌
const d = [...a, ...b] // [1,2,3,4] ✅
```

The only situation where you wouldn't use the `...` spread operator when creating a new array is when adding individual items like so:

```js
const a = [1,2]
const b = 5
const c = [...a, ...c] // ❌
const d = [...a, b] // ✅
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}]
const b = [{c: 3}, {d: 4}]

const c = [ ...a, ...b ]
const d = [ a, b ]
const e = [ ...a, b ]
const f = [ a, ...b ]

console.log(c)
console.log(d)
console.log(e)
console.log(f)
```

Comment: You should probably add at least a minimal amount of explanation about what your code does, or what you are trying to demonstrate.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).